remove all whitespaces from the headers of a polars dataframe
I'm reading some csv files where the column headers are pretty annoying: they contain whitespaces, tabs, etc.
A      B    C      D    E
CD  E   300 0   0   0
CD  E   1071    0   0   0
K   E   390 0   0   0

I want to read the file, then remove all whitespaces and/or tabs from the column names. Currently I do
import polars as pl
file_df = pl.read_csv(csv_file,
                      comment_prefix='#',
                      separator='\t')
file_df = file_df.rename(lambda column_name: column_name.strip())

Is this the "polaric" way to do it? I'm not a big fan of lambdas, but if the only other solution is to write a function just for this, I guess I'll stick to lambdas.

Looks like idiomatic polars code to me.

Also, there is an open issue on the polars GitHub requesting an option to skip whitespaces when reading a file.

You can also remove the lambda  .rename(str.strip)

.rename() executes a function at the Python level. In Python, str.strip(" foo ") is another way of writing " foo ".strip() - it's not really an answer as it only works for specific functions. (previous comment had an unfortunate typo)

The solution is to use a function as you have shown.
However, in the case of .strip() without arguments it can be simplified slightly.
Another way to write the strip is by using str.strip()
>>> " A ".strip()
# 'A'
>>> str.strip(" A ")
# 'A'

str.strip and the lambda in this case do the same thing:
one = lambda column: column.strip()
two = str.strip

>>> one(" A ")
# 'A'
>>> two(" A ")
# 'A'

df.rename() runs a function at the Python level, meaning we can pass str.strip directly.
import polars as pl

csv = b"""
A \t B \t C
1\t2\t3
4\t5\t6
"""

df = pl.read_csv(csv, separator="\t")

>>> df.columns 
# [' A ', ' B ', ' C']
>>> df.rename(str.strip).columns
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> df.rename(str.lower).columns
# [' a ', ' b ', ' c']

It's only useful if you're calling functions without additional arguments.
For anything more complex, you'll need to use a lambda (or def).

If you really want to keep it in the polars family you can do
df.columns=pl.Series(df.columns).str.strip_chars()

